# PRISM Logging to GUI

Tags: wpf, logging, prism

Using WPF/PRISM I want to log my messages through `ILoggerFacade` to my GUI (A statusbar and a logging window). The problem is that the `CreateLogger()` function gets called so early in the bootstrapping process, that I cant resolve a `IEventAggregator`.

What's the correct way of logging to GUI with the all available `ILoggerFacade`?

Thanks,
Mathieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell is created very late in the bootstrapping process, so there won't even be a window to show the initial log messages coming from the bootstrapper.

If you want to log any later messages to the GUI, you can override the `ConfigureContainer` method and do something like this

```
protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();

    ((MyLoggerAdapter)this.Logger).EventAggregator =
        Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
}
```

where `MyLoggerAdapter` is the type of the logger you've created in your `CreateLogger` override.
Then in your implementation of `MyLoggerAdapter` you can have

```
public void Log(string message, Category category, Priority priority)
{
    if (EventAggregator != null)
    {
        // Perform logging that requires EventAggregator.
    }
}
```